# ¿Que puedo hacer para que cuando termine de ejecutar mi script, se cierre automáticamente la terminal que lo este ejecutó?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
kill -9 $$
```

---

```
kill $PPID
```

Pero el problema es que cada que termina de ejecutarse. El PPID ó el PID cambian!. por lo que no cierra la terminal que debería..., Esto porque ocurre?

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `exit`?

Comment: Si, aunque eso no tendría mucho sentido, ya que tan solo finalizaría mi script, pero no la sesión de la terminal. De igual forma gracias

Comment: Funciona cuando cuando haces *sourcing*: `. tuScript`

Answer (score 1):

La solución era la siguiente:

```
    kill -9 $PPID
```

Lo que sucedía aquí es: Primero existe el proceso padre de todos, el cual ejecuta la terminal. Luego existe otro subproceso hijo que ejecuta mi script(PID), y luego en el momento en el que ejecuto mi script, se crea otro hijo (proceso), quien obviamente convierte en padre al PID.
Así que cuando yo mataba todos los procesos que pudiese matar con -9, no alcanzaba llegar al proceso padre que ejecutaba mi terminal, que era el proceso que yo quería matar. y lo mismo sucedía con `kill $PPID`.
Por lo tanto, si querías cerrar la terminal, tenías que matar al "abuelo". y eso se resuelve con el comando `kill -9 $PPID`, que lo que indica es que mate a todos los procesos que tenga alcance, incluyendo al padre, que sería el abuelo.